# Extracting TLS secrets in Go

Tags: go, ssl, wireshark

I'm not totally sure whether this is really a Wireshark, Go, or Syncthing question; I tried [the Wireshark dev list](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/202206/msg00005.html) and [the Go dev list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/dp70565acRA) but got no response, so I figured I'll try here:

I'm working on [a Wireshark Syncthing dissector](https://%5B2%5D%20https://github.com/tmo1/wireshark-syncthing-dissector). Since most of the Syncthing protocols are encapsulated in TLS, I need to provide the TLS secrets to Wireshark.

I read [the Wireshark TLS documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS); Syncthing is written in Go, so [I patched it to export TLS secrets](https://github.com/tmo1/syncthing/blob/f770faca1bee4d5b12346c5ac78cd4f6ac3a6012/lib/syncthing/syncthing.go#L273), like this (this is just Syncthing upstream code with the addition of the two final lines):

```
// The TLS configuration is used for both the listening socket and outgoing
// connections.

var tlsCfg *tls.Config
if a.cfg.Options().InsecureAllowOldTLSVersions {
    l.Infoln("TLS 1.2 is allowed on sync connections. This is less than optimally secure.")
    tlsCfg = tlsutil.SecureDefaultWithTLS12()
} else {
    tlsCfg = tlsutil.SecureDefaultTLS13()
}
tlsCfg.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{a.cert}
tlsCfg.NextProtos = []string{bepProtocolName}
tlsCfg.ClientAuth = tls.RequestClientCert
tlsCfg.SessionTicketsDisabled = true
tlsCfg.InsecureSkipVerify = true

// The following two lines open a file in the current directory and configure the application to dump its TLS secrets there
// See: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#example-Config-KeyLogWriter

w, err := os.OpenFile("tls-secrets.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
tlsCfg.KeyLogWriter = w
```

This works, and various stuff is written to the specified file, but providing that file to Wireshark doesn't enable TLS decryption. I examined the file, and I see that it contains `CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`, and `SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0` lines, but not the crucial `CLIENT_RANDOM` lines. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, with a lot of help from @zangw. There were two problems:

- Although [some discussions](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2020/12/28/decrypting-tls-streams-with-wireshark-part-2/) of TLS decryption in Wireshark mention `CLIENT_RANDOM`, this is only for TLS 1.2; current Syncthing generally uses TLS 1.3, which involves the other secrets I was seeing (`CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`, and `SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`) - see [the official documentation of the NSS Key Log Format](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/security/nss/legacy/key_log_format/index.html).
- I was starting the capture too late (since I was waiting for the secrets to be written out to the file in order to be able to provide them to Wireshark), and so Wireshark was missing the initial TLS handshake, which resulted in the misidentification of the protocol as TLS 1.2 instead of 1.3 as well as the inability to decrypt the traffic. The correct way to proceed is to start the capture **before** the TLS negotiation begins, and then subsequently provide Wireshark with the secrets file after it is created. (This may require saving and reloading the capture.)

Wireshark now successfuly decrypts the TLS data; it can be viewed by selecting "Encrypted Application Data" and then clicking on the "Decrypted TLS" tab at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is the difference between `tls1.2` and `tls1.3`, the difference  could be found [here](https://www.a10networks.com/glossary/key-differences-between-tls-1-2-and-tls-1-3/)
[image]

Per golang [tls code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/common.go#L1329)

```
    keyLogLabelTLS12           = "CLIENT_RANDOM"
    keyLogLabelClientHandshake = "CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET"
    keyLogLabelServerHandshake = "SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET"
    keyLogLabelClientTraffic   = "CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0"
    keyLogLabelServerTraffic   = "SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0"
```

- For `tls1.3`, those parameters `CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET`, `CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`, and `SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`  could be exported as client secrets
- For `tls1.2`, `CLIENT_RANDOM` could be exported as client secrets

All of them could be used in Wireshark to decrypt TLS1.2 and TLS 1.3.

---

Here is one test sample

First, start one HTTPS server

```golang
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if req.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.NotFound(w, req)
            return
        }
    })

    w, err := os.OpenFile("/keypath/https-key.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to open file err %+v", err)
        return
    }

    cs := make([]uint16, len(cipherSuites))
    copy(cs, cipherSuites)
    var tlsCfg tls.Config
    tlsCfg.Certificates = make([]tls.Certificate, 1)
    tlsCfg.Certificates[0], err = tls.LoadX509KeyPair(*certFile, *keyFile)
    tlsCfg.NextProtos = []string{"h2"}
    tlsCfg.ClientAuth = tls.RequestClientCert
    tlsCfg.SessionTicketsDisabled = true
    tlsCfg.InsecureSkipVerify = true
    tlsCfg.KeyLogWriter = w
    tlsCfg.MinVersion = tls.VersionTLS13
    tlsCfg.CipherSuites = cs
    tlsCfg.PreferServerCipherSuites = true

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:      *addr,
        Handler:   mux,
        TLSConfig: &tlsCfg,
    }

    log.Printf("Starting server on %s", *addr)
    err = srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
    log.Fatal(err)
```

Then, test it through `curl` with `tls1.3` `curl -Lv  https://localhost:4000 --cacert /crtpath/ca.crt --tlsv1.3`

We could find the content of `https-key.txt` as below

```
> cat https-key.txt
CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET xxxx yyyyy
SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET xxxx yyyyyyyyy
CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 xxxxxxx yyyy
SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 xx yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Then set the keyFile `/keypath/grpc-key.txt` to `Preferences -> Protocols -> TLS -> (Pre)-Master-Secret log filename` in WireShark, now the Wireshark could do TLS decryption

For TLS1.2 test, you could change the server code to `tlsCfg.MinVersion = tls.VersionTLS12` and then test it through `curl` with `tls1.2` `curl -Lv  https://localhost:4000 --cacert /crtpath/ca.crt --tlsv1.2`. And check the `https-key.txt` again, you could find the content could be `CLIENT_RANDOM xxxxxx yyyyyyyy`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's still not working in my case, but perhaps we're getting closer to the root of the problem. Syncthing uses TLS 1.3 (as per the cited code and its log output), but Wireshark is identifying all the Syncthing packets as TLS 1.2. I guess that would explain why it can't decode them. I understand that for reasons of backward compatibility, it can be tricky to distinguish between 1.2 and 1.3 - is this a bug in Wireshark, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @atrocia6, Are you using the latest version WireShark? The tls1.3 could be decrypted well in my WireShark V3.6.6.

Comment: @atrocia6, Could you please try to use tls1.2 through enable InsecureAllowOldTLSVersions to test whether wireshark could decrypt tls1.2?

Comment: I'm using Wireshark 3.6.6 as well. I'm not sure how I can easily get Syncthing to use TLS 1.2 - even if I enable InsecureAllowOldTLSVersions on both clients, I assume they'll still use 1.3 since they both support it, unless I either build an old version of Syncthing that has no 1.3 support, or patch the current code to require 1.2.

Comment: @atrocia6, it is so weird, per code, IMO, InsecureAllowOldTLSVersions could enable TLS 1.2.